# How to calculate sum of two event till the condition breaks in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests, pandas-groupby

Example:
I want to find Deviation of a vehicles:
Deviation defination:

Driving more than 4 hours without a break of at least 1 hour in total. The break of 1 hour can be divided into breaks of 15 minutes each. Any break of less than 15 minutes will not be counted as a break.
Transit = Vehicle is running
& Stop = break

To count deviation:
Each hour of continuous driving beyond 4 hours will be counted as 1 instance. E.g. if the vehicle drives for 5 hours and 2 minutes at a stretch then the count will be 2 (5th hour and the 2 minutes of 6th hour)

Unable to build this logic.

following is the toy data link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oWl6_k5KxTkztKAaYb6nO2PcI3gBs2RH/view?usp=sharing

I have tried this: but I am not getting what to do further:

```
out['StartDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(out['StartDate'].dt.date.astype(str)+ ' '+ out['StartTime'].astype(str))
out['EndDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(out['EndDate'].dt.date.astype(str)+ ' '+ out['EndTime'].astype(str))
out['Duration'] =  (out['EndDateTime'] - out['StartDateTime']).astype('timedelta64[m]')

itr = 0
run = 0
stop = 0
dfg = out.groupby(['companyid','Vehicle'])
df_newout = pd.DataFrame()
while itr in (enumerate(out)):
    
         
    if run < 240 & stop < 60:
         run = out[out['EventType'] == 'Transit']['Duration'].sum()
         stop = out[out['EventType'] == 'Stop']['Duration'].sum()
         run.append(itr)
         stop.append(itr)
       
        
itr = itr+1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you provide what you've tried so far and the issues you are facing?

Comment: Hi , Welcome to SO, please take the tour and read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , and create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) . You can refer this post to create a dummy example and your expected data: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) . It might be overwhelming in the beginning but will help you attract good answers for this and future questions.

Comment: @PacketLossI thanks, I have edited my trials.You can check it.I know it's not making any sense. Please help.

Comment: @anky sure, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This was a bit of a complicated problem to solve. Anyway,  here's the solution. See if this is what you wanted. Based on the current data provided, there are no violations.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
data = pd.read_csv("toydata.csv") 

out = pd.DataFrame(data)

#calculate duration

out['StartDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(out['StartDate'].astype(str) + ' ' + out['StartTime'].astype(str))
out['EndDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(out['EndDate'].astype(str)+ ' '+ out['EndTime'].astype(str))
out['Duration'] =  (out['EndDateTime'] - out['StartDateTime']).astype('timedelta64[m]')

#set violation and instances to default values
out['Violation'] = ''
out['Instances'] = 0

#use r for transit and s for stop to cumulate the duration
r = 0
s = 0

#use for checking if prev row matches. r and s will be reset if new pair found
prev_cid = ''
prev_veh = ''

#iterate through the dataframe
for i,j in out.iterrows():
    #check if we encountered new set of companyid and vehicle pair
    if j['companyid'] != prev_cid or j['Vehicle'] != prev_veh: s = r = 0

    #store current value for next iteration
    prev_cid = j['companyid']
    prev_veh = j['Vehicle']

    #add to transit (r) and stop (s) counters
    if j['EventType'] == 'Transit': r += j['Duration']
    if j['EventType'] == 'Stop ': s += j['Duration']

    #if stop is less than 60 mins and transit > 240, then flag that row as violation
    if s < 60:
        if r > 240 and j['EventType'] == 'Transit' : out['Violation'][i] = True 

    #if we reached 15 minutes of stop, then check for instances of violations
    if j['EventType']=='Stop ' and j['Duration'] >= 15:
        if r > 240: #more than 4 hrs gets 1 violation
            r-=240
            r = 1 + int(r/60) #for every 60 mins > 4hrs, add a violation
            out['Instances'][i-1] = r #record the violation to the row above. current row is stop
        s = r = 0  #since we reached valid break, reset r and s
```

You can add these two lines to find out how many were in violations.

```
newout = out[out['Instances'] > 0]
print(newout)
```

Or you can check for violation using:

```
newout = out[out['Violation'] == True]
print(newout)
```

Based on the data provided, I did not see any violations. If you manually counted and found a violation, then let me know so I can fix the logic in the code.

Comment: Hello, I have applied this code on my whole data but I am getting the same output as when I simply apply filter as out['Duration'] >= 240] and also when violation =  true still it is showing instances = 0

Comment: In this link there is new data and there is a violation here see how the output it is throwing...actually I also want start and end time when the deviation started    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rZoif4OqsrgJEUh6X3J1XkwQgeam02fi/view?usp=sharing